# Register Java Class in Flink Cluster

Tags: cassandra, apache-flink, flink-streaming, datastax-java-driver

I am running my Fat Jar in Flink Cluster which reads Kafka and saves in Cassandra, the code is,

```
        final Properties prop = getProperties();
        final FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> flinkConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>
                                             (kafkaTopicName, new SimpleStringSchema(), prop);
        flinkConsumer.setStartFromEarliest();

        final DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(flinkConsumer);
        DataStream<Person> sensorStreaming = stream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, Person>() {
            @Override
            public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Person> out) throws Exception {
                try {
                    out.collect(objectMapper.readValue(value, Person.class));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    logger.error("Json Processing Exception", e);
                }
            }
        });
        savePersonDetails(sensorStreaming);
        env.execute();
```

and The Person POJO contains,

```
    @Column(name = "event_time")
    private Instant eventTime;
```

There is codec required to store `Instant` as below for Cassandra side,

```
final Cluster cluster = ClusterManager.getCluster(cassandraIpAddress);
cluster.getConfiguration().getCodecRegistry().register(InstantCodec.instance);
```

When i run standalone works fine, but when i run local cluster throws me an error as below,

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [timestamp <-> java.time.Instant]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:526)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:506)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$200(CodecRegistry.java:140)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:211)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:208)
```

I read the below document for registering,

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/custom_serializers.html

but `InstantCodec` is 3rd party one. How can i register it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, there was `LocalDateTime` which was emitting from and when i was converting with same type, there was above error. I changed the type into java.util `Date` type then it worked.